# jquery images active/inactive loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

Here is my code

```
$(function(){
    var $list = $('.my-loading-list'),
        $imgs = $list.find('img'),
        animateImages = function(){
            var active = 0;
            setInterval(function(){
                active = $list.find('img.active').index();
                if(active > $imgs.length){
                    active = 0;
                } else {
                    active++;
                }
                $imgs.attr('src', 'https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/cool-me-down-thermometers/70/Weather_cloudy_grey-128.png');
                $imgs.eq(active).addClass('active').attr('src', 'https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/vibrant-weather/70/Colour_Weather_cloudy_grey-128.png');
            }, 300);

            setInterval(function(){
                $imgs.removeClass('active');
            }, 600);
        };

    animateImages();
});
```

And here is the snippet:

https://jsfiddle.net/8d4xfjgt/

I need to animate the third image as well. one and two are changing their source but not the third one.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to change the 3 images, one by one like this, or all at the same time?
The problem is this value isn't updating correctly active = $list.find('img.active').index(). It's taking values -1,0 alternatively

```
$(function(){
        var $list = $('.my-loading-list'),
            $imgs = $list.find('img'),

            animateImages = function(){
                var active = 0;
                setInterval(function(){



                    if(active > $imgs.length){
                        active = 0;
                    } else {
                        active++;
                    }
                    $imgs.attr('src', 'https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/cool-me-down-thermometers/70/Weather_cloudy_grey-128.png');
                    $imgs.eq(active).addClass('active').attr('src', 'https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/vibrant-weather/70/Colour_Weather_cloudy_grey-128.png');
                }, 150);

                setInterval(function(){
                    $imgs.removeClass('active');
                }, 150);
            };

        animateImages();
    });
```

Comment: I want to animate one, two, three then back to one, two, three infinitely like the loading spinner.

Comment: that's make me happy!! best